# truncating compressed files on some browsers

Tags: iis, azure, google-chrome, arr, windows

I am experiencing a weird file truncation issue on downloads from my site. I am using Azure IIAS with two Application Request Routing servers on a load balanced Azure endpoint. Those ARR servers are routing the requests to IIS8 web server.

What happens is when you request the .exe using Google Chrome as the browser, the file is truncated every other time and the user receives a message like

> "setup.exe is not commonly installed and could be dangerous"

Another user reported the same issue on IE8. Some troubleshooting I have done

- IF you right click the file and select download it works every time.
- I have verified that if I download directly from the web server or the ARR server there is no truncation
- narrowing the request to a single web server and ARR server also did not resolve the problem. It is only when the request  is made through Azure's load balanced endpoints that this is happening.
- I Also found that smaller files (~100Kb) do not experience this problem, but for larger files (~600kb) the error occurs almost every time.
- The same behavior occurs with .zip files
- I checked the IIS logs and the server reports 200, the file was downloaded fully
- I tried to use Wireshark to pin down the source of the error, but did not find anything useful

Has anyone seen anything like this before?